accessing ADO's work items via REST API from a single page application
what can I do to make it so users can login using their ADO accounts then fetch those workitems from my react app?
I am currently trying to connect my SPA with azure devops, so I fetch some work items, what I have done so far is to successfully connect using my organisation's account to my application
what remains from here (if the previous step is the right thing to do) is to use this authentication to call the get workitem API, but I don't know what to give the endpoint for authentication, most use cases I found online make use of personal access tokens, which doesn't apply to my use case because
1- multiple users will utilize this app
2- PATs have expiration dates

The Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js) enables javascript application developers to setup interactive authentication flows and obtain access tokens for API usage.
You can use Microsoft Authentication Library for React: A wrapper of the msal-browser library for apps using React. Here is the samples for your reference.
